# MySQLi query keeps returning an error

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone help me figure out why I keep getting an error?

Thanks!

Error
There was an error running the query [Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause']

code

```
$pagina = 'test';

$sql_pag = <<<SQL
    SELECT * 
    FROM `paginas` 
    WHERE `naam` = $pagina
SQL;

    if(!$result_pag = $db->query($sql_pag)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }

    while($row_pag = $result_pag->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row_pag['inhoud'];
    }
```

table layout

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paginas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` text NOT NULL,
  `inhoud` text NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

table contents

```
id | naam | inhoud 
1 | test | contents
```

Comment: I was so confused when I clicked the question (before you rolled it back) and just saw blackslashes and someone actually responded.

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround with quotes your variable if it is a string and your `naam` column is text so do it.

```
WHERE `naam` = '$pagina'
```

Comment: Actually that shouldn't say "if not an integer" but rather "if it's a string".